# Copying a file into char array dynamically

Tags: c

I have code for copying a text file (not binary) into an array of chars.

I am trying to copy the contents of a `.txt` file into a `char*` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_not_binary(const void *data, size_t len)
{
    return memchr(data, '\0', len) != NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* file_name="./bash_example.sh";
    FILE *file = fopen (file_name, "r");

    size_t size = 64;
    const size_t line_size = 300;
    char *mem = malloc(size);

    if (mem == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *mem = 0;        

    if (file != NULL && is_not_binary(file_name,line_size)) {

        char* line = malloc(line_size);

        while (fgets(line, line_size, file) != NULL)  {

            size_t total = strlen(mem) + strlen(line) + 1;
            if (size < total) {
                    size_t newsize = (total & ~1U) << 1;
                    char *tmp = realloc(mem, newsize);
                    if (tmp == NULL) {
                            perror("realloc");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    mem = tmp;
                    size = newsize;
            }
            strcat(mem, line);

        }
    }

    printf("%s",mem);

    return 0;
}
```

But in my code I must specify a static size:

```
size_t size = 64;
const size_t line_size = 300;
```

I want to remove this and I want dynamic allocation, is it possible?
Actually it's static code, 64 and 300.

Comment: you are already using `realloc` to dynamically change the buffer size, what exactly is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: note that `strcat(mem, line);` has a quadratic effect: each time you're calling it, you're reading the whole `mem` again to find the end of the string. When the file is big, it takes a lot of time.

Comment: There are multiple ways of getting the size of the file, and allocate the exact amount needed. As well as the possibility to reallocate as you go along (which you seem to do now already).

Comment: And what is the `is_not_binary` function supposed to do? Why are you calling it passing the *file name*? With a length much longer than the actual file name string?

Comment: You might consider using `read` or `fread` instead of `fgets` so you can read a fixed number of bytes each iteration. (This approach would also work with binary files, but that's no reason not to use it with text files. The functions specific for text files allow you to read a file line by line, but if that is not required, there's no harm in using the binary file functions.)

Answer (score 1):

I coded up an example that makes use of fopen, fread, and the classic example doubling the buffer size as the content grows.

```
int main()
{

    const size_t initial_size = 1024;
    char* contents = (char*)malloc(initial_size);
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t allocated = initial_size;

    FILE* file = fopen("./sbatch_example.sh", "r");
    if (file)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            size_t remaining = allocated - length;
            size_t result = 0;

            if (remaining == 0)
            {
                contents = (char*)realloc(contents, allocated*2);
                allocated = allocated*2;
                remaining = allocated-length;
            }

            result = fread(contents+length, 1, remaining, file);
            length += result;

            if (result==0) /* EOF */
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (file)
    {
        fclose(file);
        file = NULL;
    }

    /* at this point, "contents" is your file data bytes
       and "length" is the number of bytes copied into that array*/

    /*optional: append a null char to the end of the buffer to make  it easier for debugging and print statements */
    contents = (char*)realloc(contents, length+1);
    contents[length] = '\0';


    free(contents);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have potential problems by not checking return of your `[c][re]alloc()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ftell() to get the total length in advance and fread() to read a whole at one time as below.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("./sbatch_example.sh", "r"); 
if (fp) {
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  size_t size = ftell(fp);
  rewind(fp);
  char *mem = malloc(size+1);
  size_t nr = fread(mem, size, 1, fp);
}
```

Comment: Having allocated space for a null byte, don't forget to set it.  In theory, it would be a good idea to check that `nr` is equal to `1`, indicating that the file was not truncated between the `ftell()` and the `fread()`.  Or you could reverse the paremeters `fread(mem, 1, size, fp)` and check that the value in `nr` is `size`, but you'll know how many bytes were read even if the file was truncated.  You'll never know about a file that grew while you were accessing it (but that's normal — very few programs deal with that possibility).

Comment: The return value from `ftell()` on a _text_ file does not necessarily represent the number of character that will be read.  `size` can easily be more than `nr`.

Comment: @chux, that's right. I missed. I revised my answer to add "rewind" before "fread". Thanks for the notice.